# Improving a VBA Switch to auto-update as new data arrives

Tags: excel, vba, xlookup

I have a VBA Switch that switches between two sets of data, it is written as follows:

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If ToggleButton1.Value = False Then
    ToggleButton1.Caption = "Switch to 2"
    Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("G3") = "Label1-1"
    Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("Z3") = "Label1-2"
    Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("AS3") = "Label1-3"
    Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("BL3") = "Label1-4"
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E3:Q737").Copy Range("G6")
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("R3:AD737").Copy Range("Z6")
    Range("BL6:BL740").Value = WorksheetFunction.XLookup(Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("$A6:$A740"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("$A6:$A624"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("F$6:F$624"), "", 0, 1)
    Range("BM6:BM740").Value = WorksheetFunction.XLookup(Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("$A6:$A740"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("$A6:$A624"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("G$6:G$624"), "", 0, 1)
    Range("BN6:BN740").Value = WorksheetFunction.XLookup(Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("$A6:$A740"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("$A6:$A624"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("H$6:H$624"), "", 0, 1)
    Range("BO6:BO740").Value = WorksheetFunction.XLookup(Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("$A6:$A740"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("$A6:$A624"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("I$6:I$624"), "", 0, 1)
    Range("BP6:BP740").Value = WorksheetFunction.XLookup(Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("$A6:$A740"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("$A6:$A624"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("J$6:J$624"), "", 0, 1)
    Range("BQ6:BQ740").Value = WorksheetFunction.XLookup(Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("$A6:$A740"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("$A6:$A624"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("K$6:K$624"), "", 0, 1)
    Range("BR6:BR740").Value = WorksheetFunction.XLookup(Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("$A6:$A740"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("$A6:$A624"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("L$6:L$624"), "", 0, 1)
    Range("BS6:BS740").Value = WorksheetFunction.XLookup(Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("$A6:$A740"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("$A6:$A624"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("M$6:M$624"), "", 0, 1)
    Range("BT6:BT740").Value = WorksheetFunction.XLookup(Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("$A6:$A740"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("$A6:$A624"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("N$6:N$624"), "", 0, 1)
    Range("BU6:BU740").Value = WorksheetFunction.XLookup(Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("$A6:$A740"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("$A6:$A624"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("O$6:O$624"), "", 0, 1)
    Range("BV6:BV740").Value = WorksheetFunction.XLookup(Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("$A6:$A740"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("$A6:$A624"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("P$6:P$624"), "", 0, 1)
    Range("BW6:BW740").Value = WorksheetFunction.XLookup(Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("$A6:$A740"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("$A6:$A624"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("Q$6:Q$624"), "", 0, 1)
    Range("BX6:BX740").Value = WorksheetFunction.XLookup(Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("$A6:$A740"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("$A6:$A624"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("R$6:R$624"), "", 0, 1)
    
    
Else: ToggleButton1.Value = True
    ToggleButton1.Caption = "Switch to 1"
    Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("G3") = "Label2-1"
    Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("Z3") = "Label2-2"
    Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("AS3") = "Label2-3"
    Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("BL3") = "Label2-4"
    Worksheets("Actuals 2022-2023").Range("AJ3:AV737").Copy Range("G6")
    Worksheets("Actuals 2022-2023").Range("AW3:BI737").Copy Range("Z6")
    Range("BL6:BL740").Value = WorksheetFunction.XLookup(Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("$A6:$A740"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("$U6:$U740"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("$Z$6:$Z$740"), "", 0, 1)
    Range("BM6:BM740").Value = WorksheetFunction.XLookup(Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("$A6:$A740"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("$U6:$U740"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("$AA$6:$AA$740"), "", 0, 1)
    Range("BN6:BN740").Value = WorksheetFunction.XLookup(Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("$A6:$A740"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("$U6:$U740"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("$AB$6:$AB$740"), "", 0, 1)
    Range("BO6:BO740").Value = WorksheetFunction.XLookup(Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("$A6:$A740"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("$U6:$U740"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("$AC$6:$AC$740"), "", 0, 1)
    Range("BP6:BP740").Value = WorksheetFunction.XLookup(Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("$A6:$A740"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("$U6:$U740"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("$AD$6:$AD$740"), "", 0, 1)
    Range("BQ6:BQ740").Value = WorksheetFunction.XLookup(Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("$A6:$A740"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("$U6:$U740"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("$AE$6:$AE$740"), "", 0, 1)
    Range("BR6:BR740").Value = WorksheetFunction.XLookup(Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("$A6:$A740"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("$U6:$U740"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("$AF$6:$AF$740"), "", 0, 1)
    Range("BS6:BS740").Value = WorksheetFunction.XLookup(Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("$A6:$A740"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("$U6:$U740"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("$AD$6:$AD$740"), "", 0, 1)
    Range("BT6:BT740").Value = WorksheetFunction.XLookup(Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("$A6:$A740"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("$U6:$U740"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("$AH$6:$AH$740"), "", 0, 1)
    Range("BU6:BU740").Value = WorksheetFunction.XLookup(Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("$A6:$A740"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("$U6:$U740"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("$AI$6:$AI$740"), "", 0, 1)
    Range("BV6:BV740").Value = WorksheetFunction.XLookup(Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("$A6:$A740"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("$U6:$U740"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("$AJ$6:$AJ$740"), "", 0, 1)
    Range("BW6:BW740").Value = WorksheetFunction.XLookup(Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("$A6:$A740"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("$U6:$U740"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("$AK$6:$AK$740"), "", 0, 1)
    Range("BX6:BX740").Value = WorksheetFunction.XLookup(Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("$A6:$A740"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("$U6:$U740"), Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("$AL$6:$AL$740"), "", 0, 1)



End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Obviously this is bulky and as soon as the referenced data updates, it is likely to fail. Would there be a way to condense this? Particularly the XLOOKUPs would be great to get into one line, and then are modified to pic up when new rows are added. The columns should stay the same as they reference periods in a year, but I'd like to get it so that when new rows arrive, it includes them.

Any thoughts?

I have tried to create something along the lines of:

```
Range("BL6:BX740").Value = WorksheetFunction.XLookup(Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("$A6:$A740"), _
          Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("$U6:$U740"), _
          Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("$Z$6:$AK$740"), "", 0, 1)
```

Comment: It's "bulky" in part because you use no variables? No need to repeat (eg) `Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("$A6:$A740")` multiple times when you can put that in a variable...   Reducing the bulk of your code is a good first step towards simplifying the structure.

Comment: I see, makes sense. How would that look? Just so I can fully understand, if you want to give just an example. I appreciate it!

Comment: Let me ask this first: in that second block you have `Range("$AD$6:$AD$740")` twice - is that a typo?  Makes a difference when thinking about simplifying your code.  And is this code in a worksheet module?

Comment: So yes this code exists in a VBA Switch on one sheet, referencing two (possibly soon three) other sheets all in the same workbook. I was trying to follow the syntax of the XLOOKUP function so it may be a typo. I know it currently works. You can note that it compares Sheet3 to Sheet4, so I have a key that it references (a concatenation of 4 cells per row) between the two sheets and then fills the data based on the differences between those two sheets. Ultimately I have two semi-similar keys with data that occasionally matches, so the ultimate display should "fill in and skip the gaps"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test, but something like this would be repetitive:

```vb
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws3 As Worksheet, ws4 As Worksheet, rng As Range, bOn As Boolean
    Dim col As Range, rngSrc As Range, rng2 As Range
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws3 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet3")
    Set ws4 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet4")
    Set rng = ws3.Range("$A6:$A740")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    bOn = ToggleButton1.Value
    ToggleButton1.Caption = IIf(bOn, "Switch to 1", "Switch to 2")
    ws3.Range("G3") = IIf(bOn, "Label2-1", "Label1-1")
    ws3.Range("Z3") = IIf(bOn, "Label2-2", "Label1-2")
    ws3.Range("AS3") = IIf(bOn, "Label2-3", "Label1-3")
    ws3.Range("BL3") = IIf(bOn, "Label2-4", "Label1-4")
    
    If ToggleButton1.Value = False Then
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E3:Q737").Copy Range("G6")
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("R3:AD737").Copy Range("Z6")
        Set rngSrc = ws4.Range("F$6:F$624")
        Set rng2 = ws4.Range("$A6:$A624")
     Else
        Worksheets("Actuals 2022-2023").Range("AJ3:AV737").Copy Range("G6")
        Worksheets("Actuals 2022-2023").Range("AW3:BI737").Copy Range("Z6")
        Set rngSrc = ws4.Range("$Z$6:$Z$740")
        Set rng2 = ws4.Range("$U6:$U740")
    End If
    
    'loop over and fill destination range columns
    For Each col In Me.Range("BL6:BX740").Columns
        col.Value = WorksheetFunction.XLookup(rng, rng2, rngSrc, "", 0, 1)
        Set rngSrc = rngSrc.Offset(0, 1) 'next source column over
    Next col

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This is brilliant! It works great. Now I need to figure out how to add in another, but the scaffolding is all here. Thank you so much! 

Side question: can I just tack on another Else to add another? or do I need an Else If

Comment: Well your toggle button can only have two states, so I'm not sure how you add a third choice?   You'd need to do some re-work if you expand beyond two cases - for example those lines like `ws3.Range("G3") = IIf(bOn, "Label2-1", "Label1-1")` only have two choices.